# Receiving .async error when trying to import the firebase package

Tags: python, firebase, syntax-error

---

I'm trying to write a python script that requires a connection to firebase. I've installed the python-firebase package, but when I import it into my program using 'import firebase', I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hajel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\RFIDHandler.py", line 1, in <module>
    import firebase
  File "C:\Users\hajel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\firebase\__init__.py", line 3
    from .async import process_pool
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `async` is a keyword in Python 3.7, it looks like `firebase` is not compatible with Py3.7. Either look/wait for a compatible version of `firebase` or use Py 3.6.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 31):

The issue was fixed here [here](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase/commit/9fccf87303a27a6b7d871b0bae8336bb6070ff5b).
For some reason, the working `python-firebase` package did not make it to PyPI.

In order to fix it, `pip install` the latest version manually:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase
```

If you need a static version of the library, you could use the commit hash.  For example:

```
pip install \
    git+https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase@0d79d7609844569ea1cec4ac71cb9038e834c355
```

Comment: This must be the accepted answer in my view! Thank you @MZHm

Answer (score 27):

The problem is that `async` is a keyword in python 3.7
the solution is quite simple.

Just rename the file `async.py` to something other like `asyncn.py` and replace every `from .async import process_pool` in the files `firebase.py` , `decorators.py` and others , to `from .asyncn import process_pool`

Edit:

Also it might still persist so change it from ****init**.py** file

Answer (score 0):

ya because your action is wrong its a system-generated file 
don't comment it just follows steps

1)rename .async into .async_

2)open__init__ file and change .async into .async_

3)open firebase.py and change .async into .async_

because of .async is the keyword now is current version in python

Done>>>>>>>>>>

Answer (score -2):

I commented "#from .async import process_pool" in firebase.py and started working, it was incompatible with python  3.7

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to edit a 3rd party library and to maintain your own version. Unless obviously, it's something just for practice.
In production environments, it can be too much of a technical debt, if you need to update the library in future.

Comment: Downvoted cause it breaks the code for firebase.py and __init__.py on Python 3.8.2