# SyntaxError when passing async=True to function

Tags: python, deep-learning, fast-ai

```
from fastai.conv_learner import *
from fastai.dataset import *

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

I got following error during import

```
cuda 10.1
tensorflow = 2.0.0
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

   File
 "/home/jake/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
 line 3326, in run_code
     exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

   File "<ipython-input-6-7dcee084b5a9>", line 1, in <module>
     from fastai.conv_learner import *

   File
 "/home/jake/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/conv_learner.py",
 line 1, in <module>
     from .core import *

   File "/home/jake/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/core.py",
 line 19
     def V_(x):  return to_gpu(x, async=True) if isinstance(x, Variable) else Variable(to_gpu(x, async=True))
                                      ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The library you are using appears to be trying to use `async` as a parameter name. This is an error because `async` is a keyword. The library was probably written for an earlier version of Python. Perhaps there are updated versions of these libraries that you can get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receiving .async error when trying to import the firebase package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52133031/receiving-async-error-when-trying-to-import-the-firebase-package)

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using an out of date version of `fastai`. In current versions of Python, `async` is a keyword, so trying to use `async` as a variable or a function argument is a syntax error. The version you are using must have been written for a much older version of Python.

I just had a look at `fastai`, and the current version does not have this problem. So you need to update to a more recent version of the library that is compatible with the Python version you are using.