# How to install "python-firebase" with "pipenv"

Tags: python, firebase, pip, pipenv

**In short** 
How to install latest version of pip package `python-firebase` using pipenv when `pipenv install python-firebase` [not working](https://gitlab.com/namgivu/gcp_firebase_start/-/tree/pipenv-install-notworking)?

---

**Full detail**

To have firebase working with python code, as guided officially from firebase homepage [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start), I use `python-firebase` library as listed there.

Install it by running `pipenv install python-firebase`, [my code](https://gitlab.com/namgivu/gcp_firebase_start/-/tree/pipenv-install-notworking) resulted with below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/namgivu/code/namgivu/l/gcp/gcp_firebase_start/_.py", line 56, in <module>
    from firebase import firebase
  File "/home/namgivu/code/namgivu/l/gcp/gcp_firebase_start/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase/__init__.py", line 3
    from .async import process_pool
          ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The solution for that is to install the latest version of python-firebase, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63286825/248616), but thru the pip directly not pipenv

```
pip install git+https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase
```

I tried that with pipenv inplaceof pip, but didn't work

```
pipenv install git+https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase
```

So my question is **what to put into Pipfile** so that we can **get firebase ready-to-serve** in our python code by simple install command `pipenv install` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the doc [here](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#general-recommendations-version-control) from `pipenv`

> pipenv install is fully compatible with pip install syntax

So you could try

```
pipenv install \
    git+https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase@0d79d7609844569ea1cec4ac71cb9038e834c355#egg=python-firebase
```

as the [recommendation you have linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52133031/receiving-async-error-when-trying-to-import-the-firebase-package/63286825#63286825) suggested. Notice `#egg=python-firebase` is appended since `pipenv` requires an `#egg` fragment for version controlled dependencies.

To answer your question, the following is the `Pipfile` generated by `pipenv`, although you should rely on `pipenv` to generate this file for you.

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
python-firebase = {ref = "0d79d7609844569ea1cec4ac71cb9038e834c355", git = "https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase"}

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

Comment: I missed the part `#egg=python-firebase` and my pipenv install not working with the git+https url. Thank you for pointing it out @Wexort

Comment: So as we have to add the #egg part, I don't agree with the statement "pipenv install is fully compatible with pip" ^^ - you may discuss more @Wexort

Comment: @Nam G VU You're welcome. That is a statement from `pipenv`'s website and I agree with you on this. But since `pipenv` need that information to generate `Pipfile` which requires additional information (package name in this case), you can hardly blame it :)